# How to check an uninitialized variable if its negative?

Tags: c++, variables

I want to check a variable using "if statement" if it's negative

I started learning to code and I need help with a simple problem but I don't have a solution yet.

```
Fraction Fraction::divide(const Fraction &f)
{
Fraction tmp;
if(tmp.denum<0) //uninitalized local variable used
    {
    tmp.denum*=-1;
    }
tmp.num = (num*f.denum);
tmp.denum = denum*f.num;
return tmp;
}
```

Comment: It's uninitialized - it doesn't have any (valid) value. Why do you care about the sign of the garbage it happens to hold? Anyway, accessing an uninitialized object exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Note that C++ technically does not provide means to access uninitialized values.

Comment: *Why* do you think you need to do this? There's no reason it should be uninitialized if you want to use it

Comment: What's the point of all these manipulations of `tmp.denum`, when you later assign a value to it anyway? Half of your function doesn't make any sense.

Comment: if you hope to compute a random value this is not the right way, use _rand_ ^^

Comment: It should always be positive. Therefore checking the value then multiplying to -1. If there's any other way, I would like to know.

Comment: *What* is "it" that should always be positive?

Comment: `tmp.denum` What should I use then

Comment: Initialize it to zero then.

Comment: Shouldn't you adjust its sign **after** you compute and assign its value?

Comment: There is a bug in the constructor for the `Fraction` class. It should properly initialize the member variables. With that said I don't understand why you are trying to make use of an uninitialized value or your use of `tmp` in this function. Maybe you wanted to initialize `tmp` from the `Fraction` object that you are using. Does `Fraction` have a copy constructor?

Answer (score 3):

You can't check it because reading it causes undefined behaviour. Whatever result it gives you doesn't matter.